# How can I write to S3 through spark as chunks?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3

I'm writing to s3 using spark as an AVRO file. It's being saved as single file but I want to chunk it to multiple files while writing.

I used:

```
df.coalesce(6).write.json(path)
```

but still it's saving as a single file.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.!

Comment: you can check out this package may be it will help u https://spark-packages.org/package/knoldus/spark-s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your RDD only has one partition before the `coalesce(6)` call.
`coalesce()` does only work when reducing the number of partitions, but does nothing if it is asked to increase them:

> **coalesce(numPartitions):** Decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions

You could try using `repartition(6)` instead, which will also work if the number of partitions increases:

> **repartition(numPartitions):** Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network.

Comment: I just want to understand this abit in detail, When I make a jdbc connection, it will make a single point of connection and work on single executor. If I use repartition on the dataframe and do the trasnformations. Will the transformations be running in parallel or on the single executor?

Comment: It depends on how many executors assign to the job. If you assign only one, it will take the six parts one by one in serial. If you assign six executors, they will take each one job, and run in parallel.